# How to parse an error response with Retrofit2?

Tags: android, error-handling, retrofit2, pojo

I'm able to parse a successful 200 response no problem with a pojo for GoodData. However on a 412, I want to parse the response to get the data it returns so that I can do something with it.

I have a Pojo BadResponseData but getting the response body for it it’s always null. I’ve tried using a converter, but this requires having a retrofit instance to work from which I can’t seem to get. What am I missing? I can't find anything in the Android docs that have helped me understand how this works.

Eg:

```
    public void onResponse(Call<CheckInData> call, Response<GoodData> response) {
            if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                GoodData goodData = response.body();
                if (goodData!= null) {
                  //do something
                } 
            } else {
                BadResponseData badResponseData = response.body();
        //badResponseData is always null!! Why?       
             }

…
```

The json returned with a 412:

```
{
    “dataToUse”: {
        “@name”: “A Name”,
        “@date”: "2017-12-11T18:00:00-05:00"
    },
    "serviceErrors": {
        "code": "0",
        "fields": “required.data.not.found”,
        "message": “name”
    }
}
```

And my pojo classes:

```
public class BadResponseData {
    private DataToUse dataToUse;
    public DataToUse getDataToUse() { return this.dataToUse; }
    public void setDataToUse(DataToUse dataToUse) { this.dataToUse = dataToUse; }
    private ServiceErrors serviceErrors;
    public ServiceErrors getServiceErrors() { return this.serviceErrors; }
    public void setServiceErrors(ServiceErrors serviceErrors) { this.serviceErrors = serviceErrors; }

}
public class DataToUse {
    private String name;
    public String getName() { return this.name; }
    public void setName(String name) { this.name = name; }
    private Date date;
    public Date getDate() { return this.date; }
    public void setDate(Date date) { this.date = date; }
}

public class ServiceErrors {
    private String code;
    public String getCode() { return this.code; }
    public void setCode(String code) { this.code = code; }
    private String fields;
    public String getFields() { return this.fields; }
    public void setFields(String fields) { this.fields = fields; }
    private String message;
    public String getMessage() { return this.message; }
    public void setMessage(String message) { this.message = message; }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `response.errorBody()` and parse the json:

```
ResponseBody errorBody = response.errorBody();
if (errorBody != null){
    BadResponseData error = new Gson().fromJson(errorBody.charStream(), BadResponseData.class);
}
```

Comment: BadResponseData badResponseData = response.errorBody();
This gives an error "Incompatible types. Found: 'okhttp3.ResponseBody', required: 'com.example.BadResponseData'

Comment: Thank you, that is getting me further. Now I have an issue with the JSON
"java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column 1 path"
I'll see what I can figure out about that.

Comment: @KG819 It means your response is String not object.
If I help you, you should upvote my answer and check as correct on the left side. Dont leave your question opened :)

Comment: Thanks, do I open a new question about the reponse? My json response is posted above, and is properly formatted with { }.

Comment: So this has been helpful but I'm still not able to parse the JSON.

I can see the response in Postman formatted properly as above. However it seems like errorBody.charStream() is returning it in XML format. Am I missing something here?

Comment: No, `charStream()` returns `Reader` so it have to work. Can you show url?

Comment: The URL I call? I could but I know it works because I'm already parsing the 200 response properly with another Pojo class. I'm just stumped why this is giving me so much trouble trying to parse the 400 response. If I do 
response.errorBody().string().toString() it definitely shows XML not JSON. That's why I was thinking the charStream is returning xml formatted instead of JSON.

Comment: so it means API returns XML. If you give me url I can try resolve it

Comment: Ok that got me into a better search and yes it was returning both but I was specifying Accept: application/xml instead of Accept: application/json
Many thanks, this is resolved!